# Pass variable in c# code to powershell script

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory

First time posting here, hoping its an easy question. I have the following C# code:

```cs
try
{
    Process process;
    var ps1File = @"C:\Program Files\Maximus\MFS TechTools\Scripts\Term-ADUser.ps1";
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        //CreateNoWindow = true,
        FileName = "powershell.exe",
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File \"{ps1File}\" \"{usr}\"",
        UseShellExecute = false
    };
    process = Process.Start(startInfo);
    process.WaitForExit();
    StreamReader output = process.StandardOutput;

    while (output.Peek() > -1)
    {
        ni.Append(output.ReadLine() + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    process = null;

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ni.Append((e.Message) + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

To keep it simple, the code block, start the process 'powershell.exe' and runs a PowerShell script that we will call `testscript.ps1`.

Below is the PowerShell script:

```bash
Function Set-Flag($User)  {
    try
    {
        Set-ADUser -Identity $User -CannotChangePassword $true
        $text = "Set - User Cannot Change Password Flag!"
    }
    catch
    {
        $text = $_
    }

    return $text
    quit
}
Set-Flag
```

From my C# code being, I need to pass a string variable called `usr` to the PowerShell script so that it can be used in the function in the PowerShell script.

I have seen many examples of how to do this but can't seem to wrap my head around it.

I have tried using other methods of running the script directly from C# but due to a know issue between C# and the active directory attribute `CannotChangePassword`, it produces errors.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

I tried the above C# code, expecting it to pass the value of variable `usr` to the PowerShell script.
The C# code ran the PowerShell script but did not seem to pass the value of the variable `usr` to the script.

Comment: Could you explain whats the reason for using a Process instance to invoke your powershell code instead of using a powershell instance? Do you need to run as a different user or .. ?

Comment: Please check out this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210223/passing-variables-from-c-sharp-to-powershell

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Variables from C# to Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210223/passing-variables-from-c-sharp-to-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

Your task is much easier done using the [PowerShell SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.3), unless you have a very specific need to use a Process instead then the following should do:

```cs
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace Testing;

public static class Test
{
    public static void SetFlag(object user)
    {
        using PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        ps.AddScript(@"
            param($user)

            try {
                Set-ADUser -Identity $User -CannotChangePassword $true
                ""CannotChangePassword successfully set for '$User'""
            }
            catch {
                $_.Exception.Message
            }
        ").AddParameter(nameof(user), user);

        foreach (string line in ps.Invoke<string>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```